# Smallest number divisible by $88$ using digits $1$ through $8$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest number that is made up of each of the digits $1$ through $8$ exactly once and is divisible by $88$.

Comment: $12437568$ should work, but what did you try?

Comment: I know that in order to be divisible by 11, the alternating digit sums has to be divisible by 11.But didn't know where to start

Comment: I get it, I start with two sets $\{1,3,5,7\}, \{2,4,6,8\}$ and since the sums are $16$ and $20$, I have to find a way to exchange a digit from each of these sets

Comment: Yes. good keep looking you will find the answer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a modified version of the problem at [MathsChallenge](http://mathschallenge.net/problems/pdfs/mathschallenge_3_star.pdf) (on page 29)  You should go read that and try solving yourself.

If someone else comes with a different approach, that probably will be helpful to you.

You should also mention what was your approach (You would have started somewhere, didn't you?)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long day for me so far but if the number is divisible by $88$ shouldn't it therefore be divisible by $11$? If that's the case shouldn't the last two digits be $\ldots 21$?

Comment: I think he is looking for smallest number that uses all the digits from $1$ to $8$ that is divisible by 88

Comment: An odd number divisible by $88$?

Comment: I know, I know I'm easily confused! Thanks to both - I see now that it needs to be the \emph{smallest} number!